# Issue provisioning Databricks workspace resources using Terraform

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-databricks

I have defined resource to provision databricks workspace on Azure using Terraform as follows which consumes the list ( of inputs from tfvar file for # of workspaces) and provision them.

```
resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "workspace" {
  for_each            = { for r in var.databricks_workspace_list : r.workspace_nm => r}
  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
  location            = each.value.location
  sku                 = "standard"

  tags = {
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}
```

I am trying to create additional resource as below

```
resource "databricks_instance_pool" "smallest_nodes" {
  instance_pool_name = "Smallest Nodes"
  min_idle_instances = 0
  max_capacity       = 300
  node_type_id       = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id // data block is defined
  idle_instance_autotermination_minutes = 10
}
```

To create instance pool, I need to pass workspace id in databricks provider block as below

```
provider "databricks" {
azure_client_id= *******
azure_client_secret= *******
azure_tenant_id= *******

azure_workspace_resource_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace.workspace.id

}
```

But when I do `terraform plan`, it fails with below error

```
Missing resource instance key
azure_workspace_resource_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace.workspace.id

Because azure_workspace_resource_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace has for_each set, its attribute must be accessed on specific instances.
For example, to correlate indices , use :
azurerm_databricks_workspace[each.key]
```

I couldnt use for_each in provider block, also not able to find out way to index workspace id in provider block.
Appreciate your inputs.

TF version : 0.13

Azure RM : 3.10.0

Databricks : 0.5.7

Comment: This question may be moot because I believe only `data` from another provider is allowed in a provider block, and not resource attributes from another provider.

Comment: you can perfectly refer to the attributes from other resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can create multiple workspaces when you're using `for_each` in the `azurerm_databricks_workspace` resource. But your provider block is trying to refer to  a "generic" resource instance, so it's complaining.

The solution here would be either:

- Remove `for_each` if you're creating just one workspace
- instead of `azurerm_databricks_workspace.workspace.id`, you need to refer `azurerm_databricks_workspace.workspace[<name>].id` where the `<name>` is the specific instance of Databricks from the list of workspaces.

P.S. Your `databricks_instance_pool` resource doesn't have explicit `depends_on`, so the operation will fail with authentication error as described [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/guides/troubleshooting#data-resources-and-authentication-is-not-configured-errors).